# Chrome fails axios xhr request, as no origin is included

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, axios, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send post request from react/axios to django rest. CORS configs on django is properly set to response to all origins.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

And this is the axios instance I've created:

```
const axiosPublic = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  },
});
```

And this is the request I send:

```
axiosPublic
  .post("accounts/check_number/", {
    phone_number: data.number,
  })
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      console.log(res.data)
    }
  })

  // Catch errors if any
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

when request is fired, a **preflight** is fired and gets response 200, then a **xhr** is fired without ***origin*** header, which gets this error:

```
code: 
"ERR_NETWORK"
config: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message: 
"Network Error"
name: 
"AxiosError"
request: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack: 
"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:176:14)"
[[Prototype]]: 
Error
```

and finally a fetch request is fired to the same endpoint which gets response 200.

**But**, response of **xhr** is considered as the response, and nothing is working.

On Firefox everything is OK, but on Chrome I have this problem. And on Chrome, it is resolved when I do a hard refresh (Cnrl + F5)!